# How to resolve Qt native dependencies when creating dll from Qt to be able to use it on other platform

Tags: c++, qt

I am building a dll using qt with native qt variables like QString and those are my configurations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

So I'll have this global header:

[image]

And this dll's header in which my functions are defined:

[image]

When adding the generated dll to my project in visual studio I'm getting this because I'm using native qt in my dll:

[image]

Is there a way to resolve dependencies in order to use this dll in visual studio or anything rather than qt?

I also tried to build it using CMake:
CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(CMakeLib LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)

add_library(CMakeLib SHARED
  CMakeLib_global.h
  cmakelib.cpp
  cmakelib.h
)

target_link_libraries(CMakeLib PRIVATE Qt5::Core)

target_compile_definitions(CMakeLib PRIVATE CMAKELIB_LIBRARY)
```

but it also gave the same result as before

Comment: Is generating (or writing) a CMake config module an option?

Comment: Also, don't mix up Qt the framework and Qt creator the IDE.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, post the code as text. As you're using Qt in your headers you'll need to build the code that uses this dll as a Qt library/application too. Do you really need to use `QString`? Can you use `std::string` instead?

Comment: @Botje I want to use native Qt variables I'm not sure if it can be done using CMake.

Comment: CMake is an officially supported build system for Qt applications (it might even be the preferred one). It's just a matter of calling `find_package(Qt6 ...)` and declaring Qt as a transitive dependency of your library.

Comment: @AlanBirtles this was a simple code just to describe my situation that's why I posted images instead of text. And yes I need to use the QString instead of std::string if it is possible

Comment: Anyway, either you provide instructions for the build system from the provider side or you configure the consumer application with the proper paths to Qt. Your call.

Comment: @Botje now CMake looks like this
```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(CMakeLib LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)
add_library(CMakeLib SHARED
  CMakeLib_global.h
  cmakelib.cpp
  cmakelib.h
)
target_link_libraries(CMakeLib PRIVATE Qt5::Core)
target_compile_definitions(CMakeLib PRIVATE CMAKELIB_LIBRARY)
```
I don't know if I'm missing something but it didn't resolve dependencies

Comment: Don't put that in a comment. Edit your question along with any errors you get.